# Need to show Videos and images in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to show videos and images in UICollectionview.
I given URL for this view :

http://exarcplus.com/check.png

The images and videos fetch from server using JSON.

code for images fetch from server:

```
NSDictionary *appsdict = [array_all objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[appsdict objectForKey:@"url"]]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        [cell.image_gallery setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
    }];
////////but don't know how to fetch videos from server
```

Answer (score 0):

You need AsyncImageView class to import into you project and take image view and a label in the collection view cell with the given tag as explain below:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [your array count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"MyGridViewCell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    AsyncImageView *imageView = (AsyncImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:imageView];
    imageView.imageURL =[NSURL URLWithString:[your array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"product_image"]];

    UILabel *titleLabel  = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    NSString *nameText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d. %@",indexPath.row+1,[arrayforlistt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"product_name"]];
    titleLabel.text= nameText;
    return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // enter your code here if you want to perform any action on the did select of the project
}
```

Comment: the format for video is also same as images read the tag in which the video url is and store that urls in array and display that in the collection view